# Connected nodes overlapping other edges or nodes

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

I'm using vis.js to display nodes, not all nodes are connected to each other, but they are overlapping as shown in the picture, is there a way with the option to avoid this, I went through the configure options but could not find.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using manual configuration for physics and layout:

```
configure: {
  enabled: true,
  filter: 'physics, layout',
  showButton: true
}
```

and try to play with 
*nodeDistance* and *nodeSpacing*.

Answer (score 10):

There is an attribute avoidOverlap=[0,1] in some physics like BarnesHut 
http://visjs.org/docs/network/physics.html?#

You can try it here at the bottom under physics http://visjs.org/examples/network/other/configuration.html

like adding this attribute into your physics option

```
var options = {
 ... "physics": {
    "barnesHut": {
      "avoidOverlap": 1
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: I must have to many nodes because they all start dancing and moving around and never settle.

Comment: Don't start with 1. Try .1 and slowly work your way up. I have a lot of nodes, so 1 made them dance around and not stop.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to get it working by using the `configure` option:

```
configure: {
        enabled: true,
        showButton: true
}
```

This shows you a modal to configure all the options until the graph looks nice.

In my case with hierarchical view, I had to disable physics and set the layout like this:

```
layout: {
  hierarchical: {
    enabled: true,
    nodeSpacing: 425,
    blockShifting: false,
    edgeMinimization: false,
    sortMethod: "directed"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of options on this and figured out that it actually it depends on the physics configuration:
if your physics configuration is  like this

```
physics: false, then you can use just this
layout: {
   hierarchical: {
      levelSeparation: 150,
      treeSpacing: 200,
      blockShifting: true,
      edgeMinimization: true,
      parentCentralization: true,
      direction: 'UD',
      nodeSpacing: 300,
      sortMethod: "directed" //directed,hubsize 
   }
},
```

Where nodeSpacing is the key for you and sord method will define the structure for you
This make up a network like this:
[image]

otherwise use manual configuration:

```
configure: {
   enabled: true,
   filter: 'physics, layout',
   showButton: true
}
```